# How to open a div inside a lightbox(lightbox, colorbox or ibox..) application which have only class-name specified?

Tags: jquery, html, lightbox

I have a div like following:

```
    <div class="photo">
    <img class="image" width="780" alt="abc/" src="some link of photo">
    ... extra content also
    </div>
```

How do I open this div in a lightbox or similar application when I click a button?

Answer (score 5):

You can use a simple lightbox plugin like Lightbox_me : http://buckwilson.me/lightboxme/

Comment: I'm using lightbox_me. Its using jquery v1.4.2. I won't work with jquery 1.9.1. Can anyone help.

Answer (score 0):

I am using [fancybox](http://fancybox.net) in following example http://fancybox.net

after including downloaded js and css files, the code will be:-

```
$("button").fancybox({
    content: $('.photo').andSelf().html();
});
```

replace "button" with the button selector.